# Combinations from different sets with weightings

Tags: distributions, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Imagine the following scenario:

I want to create 1000 unique combinations of clothing. The combinations would include the following categories: hats,  shirts, shorts, socks and shoes. Each combination would have 1 item from each category.

Each clothing category has a number of different colors available. Each color within a category also has a desired number. When the combinations have been made, the total number of each item of clothing (red hat for example) used to create the combinations should match the desired number as best as possible.

An example of the categories to make the combinations would be the following:

```
hats = [[‘yellow’, 200],[‘green’, 400], [‘blue’, 300], [‘red’, 100]]
shirts = [[‘yellow’, 200],[‘green’, 154], [‘blue’, 3], [‘red’, 200],  [‘purple’, 213],  [‘pink’, 30],  [‘black’, 50],  [‘white’, 150]]
shorts = [[‘yellow’, 200],[‘green’, 150], [‘blue’, 120], [‘red’, 200],  [‘brown’, 150],  [‘dark blue’, 180]]
socks = [[‘yellow’, 130],[‘green’, 70], [‘blue’, 300], [‘red’, 100],  [‘white’, 200],  [‘black’, 103],  [‘pink’, 97]]
shoes = [[‘brown’, 400], [‘blue’, 300], [‘black’, 100], [‘white’, 50],  [‘red’, 150]]
```

An example of 1 combination would be:

```
{
  hat: red,
  shirt: green,
  shorts: blue,
  socks: white,
  shoes: black
}
```

Using the cartesian product, I know there are 4x8x6x7x5 = 6,720 total combinations, although making all of these would obviously mean the desired amounts aren’t taken into account.

**What would be the best way of approaching this?**

Would it be easier to think about this more as ratios than desired quantities?

Some ideas I have had:

Picking a random number from the range of the sum of the desired amounts for each color in each category. I would then check whether this combination had already been made, and if not keep it. This could cause lots of collisions where two combinations are identical, leading to this being very inefficient.

Using the cartesian product, check the maximum possible number of each article of clothing (6,720/4 = 1680 for yellow hats for example). I would then find the ratio between the total number possible, and the desired number (for yellow hats 200/1680) and then favour making combinations with higher ratios first, as these will be hardest to get all the combinations for without overrunning the number of desired articles of clothing for items in other categories.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by the "number of each clothing."

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question to try and make it clearer what I meant. Basically  each category of clothing (hat/shirt etc) has an array of colors to choose from. Say a red hat had a desired number of 100, out of the 1000 total combinations made, 100 of them would have a red hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This can be expressed as a *binary linear program.***  Provided the total number of unique combinations is not prohibitively large, it can be solved efficiently.  When multiple solutions exist, usually additional ones can be found by randomizing the information first.

One way to formulate it is to *minimize* the number of unique clothing combinations needed to achieve *at least* the specified numbers of each color in each type of clothing.

Here is a graphical representation of a solution found with the methods described here.

[image: Figure]

---

**To represent this problem to the computer,** start with a data table $X$ with one column for each type of clothing and one row for each of the $6720$ unique combinations.

From $X$ construct the *indicator matrix* $A$.  For each column $j$ of $X$ and each possible color $c$ appearing in that column, create a vector $I(c,j)$ whose values are $1$ at the places $i$ where $X_{ij} = c.$  Otherwise, put zeros in $I(c,j).$  The concatenation of all $4+8+6+7+5=30$ indicator columns (in any order you please) is the indicator matrix.

Along with $A$ construct the intended *minimum* counts of each clothing type and color you wish to have in your selection.  This a vector $b$ of length $30.$

**A solution,** if it exists, will be a binary ($0,1$) vector $x$ of length $6720$ whose nonzero entries indicate which rows of $X$ to select.

- The number of combinations in such a solution is simply $1^\prime x$ where $1$ is the vector of ones of the same length as $x.$
- The numbers of articles of clothing of a given type and color are given by the $30$-vector $t(A)x.$

**In terms of the data structures $A$ and $b,$ your problem can be formulated as follows:**

> *Minimize* $1^\prime x$ *subject to* $t(A) x \ge b$ where $x\in \{0,1\}^{6720}.$

The inequalities apply component by component (to all $30$ components).

**Optimizing a linear function of $6720$ binary variables subject to $30$ linear constraints can be done relatively quickly.**  The [`Rglpk` package for `R`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/index.html), which interfaces to the open-source [GNU Linear Programming Kit](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), found a solution within 13 seconds on this workstation.  I have been able to obtain very different sets of solutions by randomly permuting the rows of $A$ and re-running the solver.

Here is an extract of one random solution as found with the `R` code below (stored in its data frame `Y`):

```
        hats shirts    shorts  socks shoes
   1:  green purple     green    red  blue
   2:  green  white    yellow   blue  blue
   3:   blue    red     green   pink  blue
   4:   blue    red dark blue yellow   red
   5:  green  green    yellow  white brown
  ---                                     
 996:  green  white     green   pink white
 997:  green   pink    yellow  white brown
 998:   blue yellow       red  white  blue
 999:  green  black     green  white brown
1000: yellow yellow     green  white brown
```

```R
#
# The original specification.
#
hats = c("yellow" =  200,"green" =  400, "blue" =  300, "red" =  100)
shirts = c("yellow" =  200,"green" =  154, "blue" =  3, "red" =  200,  
           "purple" =  213,  "pink" =  30,  "black" =  50,  "white" =  150)
shorts = c("yellow" =  200,"green" =  150, "blue" =  120, "red" =  200,  
           "brown" =  150,  "dark blue" =  180)
socks = c("yellow" =  130,"green" =  70, "blue" =  300, "red" =  100,  
          "white" =  200,  "black" =  103,  "pink" =  97)
shoes = c("brown" =  400, "blue" =  300, "black" =  100, "white" =  50,  "red" =  150)
#
# Create a data matrix of all possible combinations.
# (You could remove any undesirable combinations if you wish.)
#
X <- expand.grid(hats=names(hats),
                 shirts=names(shirts),
                 shorts=names(shorts),
                 socks=names(socks),
                 shoes=names(shoes))
#
# Compute the indicator matrix of `X`.
#
A <- lapply(X, function(x) {
  s <- sort(unique(x))
  a <- sapply(s, function(s) ifelse(x == s, 1, 0))
  colnames(a) <- s
  a
})
A <- do.call(cbind, A)
#
# Create the arguments for the solver.
#
dir <- rep(">=", ncol(A))                    # All constraints are lower bounds
rhs <- c(hats, shirts, shorts, socks, shoes) # These are the minimum counts
types <- rep("B", ncol(A))                   # All variables are binary
f <- rep(1, nrow(A))                         # The objective to minimize

set.seed(17)                                 # (Makes this reproducible)
j <- sample.int(nrow(A))                     # Scramble the rows of the data
library(Rglpk)
system.time( # Benchmark smaller versions of the problem first!
  obj <- Rglpk_solve_LP(f, t(A[j, ]), dir, rhs, types = types, max = FALSE)
)
#
# Extract the rows of `X` given by the solution.
#
Y <- X[j[obj$solution == 1], ]
#
# Do whatever you like with the solution.
#
lapply(Y, table)
```

As a check, this code winds up by tabulating the numbers of each article by color.  When all is successful, this tabulation will agree with the original specification (which it does).

```
$hats
yellow  green   blue    red 
   200    400    300    100 

$shirts
yellow  green   blue    red purple   pink  black  white 
   200    154      3    200    213     30     50    150 

$shorts
   yellow     green      blue       red     brown dark blue 
      200       150       120       200       150       180 

$socks
yellow  green   blue    red  white  black   pink 
   130     70    300    100    200    103     97 

$shoes
brown  blue black white   red 
  400   300   100    50   150
```

**A mosaic plot** is one way to look at the solution:

```R
mosaicplot(~ hats + shorts + shoes + socks + shirts , table(Y), cex.axis=0.5, las=2,
           col=labels(shirts), main="One Solution (Colored by Shirts)")
```

[image: Figure 2]